# Doing an https POST request for token

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, microsoft-translator

I am trying to do the following request in Google Apps Script. This request would return the token to be used for accessing the API.

```
POST https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=USERS-CLIENT-ID&client_secret=USERS-SECRET-KEY&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=http%3a%2f%2fapi.microsofttranslator.com%2f
```

How do I do the above request in Google Apps Script. I am reading about it but unable to find a solution. I tried something like below, but it didn’t work.
Which methods should I use?

```
var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("bearer");
oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("USERS-CLIENT-ID");
//some code omitted
//I couldn't figure out where to put grant_type and scope 
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=hello&from=en&to=ja",options); //gave oAuth error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addOAuthService` is really only meant for OAuth 1 services.

For OAuth 2 you'll need to manually do the POST call. Here is an example

```
var parameters = {
    method : 'post',
    payload : 'client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL+'&code=' + code
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(TOKEN_URL,parameters).getContentText();
```

You can see a more fully formed example here - https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/IO2013/YouTubeAnalytics/oauth2.gs#L22